# How to add a reference input not in a form with react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin and get stack with that problem:

How should I create a component with reference input, not inside a form?

When I try to add it I get an error: `Error: useField must be used inside of a <Form> component`

I try to insert it into a form but because I do not have the props.

How can I get along with this?

EDIT:

for example:

```
      <ReferenceInput label="Post" source="post_id" reference="posts">
        <AutocompleteInput optionText="title" />
      </ReferenceInput>
      <DateInput source="" />
```

I want to call the function generate with choosen post_id and date.

But as I say I get the error:
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Add your code to the question to make it clearer what you want to do. Do you want the component to work without a form?

Comment: Yes that what I need. I added some code to explain it. thank you!

Comment: As far as I understand, this cannot be done without a form, all Input components do not work without a form.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, the react-final-form library is used here:
https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/getting-started

Perhaps this hack will help you to get a link to the form:

```
const FormCreate = (props) => {
  const formRef = useRef(null)
  ...
  formRef.current.change(YOU_FIELD_NAME, new_value) // Refer to the form via the link
  ...
  
  return (
    <Create {...rest} >
      <SimpleForm      
        <FormDataConsumer>
          { ({ formData, ...rest }) => {
            formRef.current = useForm() // Save the link to the form 
          }}
        </FormDataConsumer>      
        ...        
        
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  )
}
```